# How to get Computer Name remote computer with ıp or username?

Tags: windows, powershell

I need your help.

I have the username or ip address and I need the computer name.
How can I get the computer name with this information.  Please help me.

I had tried this, but it was not successful:

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName x.x.x.x -ScriptBlock {$env:COMPUTERNAME}`

Comment: Could you elaborate on `but not successful`? Do you get any errors? What kind of environment is this?

Comment: "*I have **username** or ıp address*", forget `username`, there is no common relationship between the user and the computer. In essence, any user can login to any computer. (You might have a customized relation, but you need to elaborate on that too if you want us to help you with that.)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, I ' ve this error + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (10:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotUseIPAddress,PSSessionStateBroken

Answer (score 0):

```
ping -a 111.222.333.444
```

The name should appear in the output
[image]